# How to describe all content from the list in SQL

Tags: development, sql

I must do Data Warehouse from my lists in Sharepoint.

I need to connect to the Sharepoint and get all elements from the list and Show them in MS SQL Serwer 2008 R2. I need to show them in another server not in this which is located Sharepoint. I must done connection across them.

I see that all content are in database called WSS_Content.

Please tell me how to list all data from another server in another server in which aren't Sharepoint instaled.

Comment: I don't really know where are but BTW you shouldn't touch it!!!

Comment: Sow how Use a Sharepoint list content from MS SQL Server ?

Comment: What are you trying to do/look at? This question is a bit too general for me to be able to answer well.

Comment: I want to take a content/data from Sharepoint Lists, and use them on MS SQL Serwer 2008. I must do from them data warehouse. Please tell me how to take from list data and put them to the warehouse.

Comment: but why u want do that?

Comment: Because I must do the data warehause from my list wchich I created in Sharepoint. That's why.

Comment: This looks to be the same as your question yesterday, so I am closing that one and merging with this one.

Answer (score 2):

Straight connections to SharePoint databases are not supported by Microsoft and should be avoid at all costs. On SharePoint 2010/2013 you can either use the Server-side Object Model API from a process running on one of your SharePoint servers or the Client Object Model API from your SQL Server towards the respective site collection - [Deciding Which SharePoint 2010 API to Use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313619%28v=office.14%29.aspx). If your farm is MOSS 2007 for remote connections you can only use web service calls to SharePoint [Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists%28v=office.12%29.aspx) web service.

Comment: But how should I connect them from data. I have got Sharepoint 2010 Server instalation. Should I write code or is there a ready solution ? Maybe should I eneble this. How should I done this ? I always write a CAML. Not conecting the data from MSSQL Server Sharepoint. Now I must preper the database in SQL which shows list content.

Comment: Meybe Could I done a Connection String to conect with Sharepoint list ? I find this artykle. Maybe this is it ?: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=794 Please Help how do the conection string.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to know that accessing data from SharePoint directly through SQL Server is not supported - even if you don't actually change anything. The only supported ways are through the user interface, the API's or via PowerShell. Just don't do it.

That said, if you really want to have a look...

First you have to determine the content database your content resides in. You can do this by issuing the following command:

Get-SPContentdatabase -Site http://[site collection url] | select name

When you have the database you can issue your queries.

An example on how to do that can be found here:
http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/07/run-sql-queries-and-fetch-list-data_10.html

Comment: I found out a good article in which is describe how to take a data, but i don't know how the autor opened the Database which he see on External Content: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=794

Comment: But i don't now hy he should first do the data base and table

Comment: I Used Your PowerShell comand and It told me that content are in WSS_Content Database.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a link to an example sql query